# Laravel 10 Image source not readable

Tags: php, laravel, image, file-upload, intervention

I want to upload an image on my app, but when I do that, I have this error "image source not readable". I checked the file path and name, all fine. I've linked the folders, but I don't know where the issue comes from. Few days ago its was working

```
    $imagePath = request('image')->store('uploads', 'public');
    $image = Image::make(public_path("/storage/app/{$imagePath}"))->fit(1200, 1200);
    $image->save();

    auth()->user()->ads()->create([
        'image' => $imagePath
    ]);
```

and my form looks like below

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <div class="form-group">
<div class="custom-file">
  <input type="file" name="image" class="custom-file-input @error('image') is-invalid @enderror" id="validatedCustomFile">
     <label class="custom-file-label" for="validatedCustomFile">Choisir une image</label>
       @error('image')
      <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
     <strong>{{ $message }}</strong></span>
       @enderror
  </div>
```

Comment: your issue might be that you have forgotten to run the `php artisan storage:link` command. Also, rather than using the `public_path` use `storage_path` for these types of cases

Comment: I already did the `php artisan storage:link` before and I tried to change `public_path` to `storage_path` but its still tell me the same error

Comment: if you used the storage_path then I believe you have updated the "/storage/app/{$imagePath}" value to the correct one, right? Also, check if the image actually exists in the path `public_path("/storage/app/{$imagePath}")`

Comment: @user21942112 Can we have a remote desktop to fix this?

Comment: yes I updated it but I have the same error again. Also i have the error even so the images are saved in the right folder, here is my public_path \storage\app\public\uploads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the "storage/app" directory and its subdirectories have appropriate permissions that allow the server to read and write.

```
chmod -R 755 storage
chmod -R 755 public/storage
```

Comment: still not working